# Hilt dependency injection error with ActivityContext

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am using Hilt. In my ViewModel, I have EventLogger class and a repository class, which are throwing me an error while being built, so build is unsuccessful. The code is as follows,

```
@HiltViewModel
class ConversionViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val preConversionUseCase : PreConversionUseCase,
    private val conversionUseCase: ConversionUseCase,
    private val conversionSmsUseCase: ConversionSmsUseCase,
    private val currencyRepository: MyBankRepository,
    private val logger: EventLogger
) : ViewModel() { ... }

class EvenLogger @Inject constructor(
    @ActivityContext val context: Context
){ ... }

class MyBankRepository @Inject constructor(
    @ActivityContext private val module: ApiModule
): ApiRequest() {
    val api = module.provideRetrofit()
}
```

I am getting the following error:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/506796

Comment: Oh okay, I see.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't inject the ActivityContext into an ApiModule. You need to add an Context-type param to the constructor of your MyBankRepository, I suppose:

```
class MyBankRepository @Inject constructor (
    @ActivityContext
    val context: Context,
    private val module: ApiModule
) : ApiRequest() { ...
```

But this does unfortunately not work for ViewModels as described here:
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2698#issuecomment-862516150
The Repository and the EventLogger are both children of a ViewModel.

So it looks like you have to chance your architecture a little bit. You shouldn't implement too much logic into an ViewModel.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. I am still getting errors as  error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ActivityContext android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method. 2 errors which show EventLogger and MyBankRepository classes

Comment: Okay, I just noticed that you are trying to inject it into a child of a ViewModel. This does not work. I added a Link to a GitHub discussion where you can see a better explanation. You shouldn't add to much logic to a ViewModel. It should just hold data that is later on displayed in a View.